# Confused by wirtinger differential operators

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

In my text the Wertinger differential operators are  defined as

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right) \qquad \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)$$.

Then the text goes on say that it is possible to show that

$$4\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\overline z}=\Delta$$ where $\Delta$ is the laplacian.

I am confused by this notation. When applied to a function $f$,  would I first compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline z}$ and feed this into $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$? Or would I compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline z}$ and then multiply the result together in some way?

Thank you

Comment: The first; it's an equality of second-order differential operators.

Comment: The partial is an operator that inputs functions and outputs functions.  So when you see the two partials together like that,  it's a composition of functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation means your first hypothesis: first compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline z}$ and feed this into $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$.